# Dialogs on Jobs are inconsistent...why?

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

Take a look at all three of these dialogs on jobs:

The first is the match preferences dialog:
[image]

The second is asking a company a question dialog:
[image]

The third is the applying for a job dialog:
[image]

Can these become more consistent across the jobs feature of SO.  For instance, the buttons on match preferences are left aligned, where as they are right aligned in the other dialogs.

The close x button is visible in match preferences but not in the others.  The CaPitiLization is inconsistent as it is completly lower case for asking a company a question but different for the other two dialogs.

### Has anyone had a chance to look into this?

Comment: Shouldn't the text *send message* not simply be *Submit*? That is then if we assume that *Save* is something else as *Submit*. Otherwise the buttons should mention what it does *Save Profile* and *Submit Resume* etc

Comment: @rene - I'd agree with that, but first let's make them consistent.  To me a popup to Apply to a job "Submit" means submit your resume.  A popup allowing me to message a company "Submit" means you are submitting the message, etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Jon. Yes, you're right. Our design and messaging patterns are underdeveloped, and lack of consistency is an increasingly bigger problem as the Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange product grows. We're addressing this in a couple different ways, but I've deferred this for now only because I don't have a tangible solution for your immediate question.

We've grown the Jobs team very recently, so I hope that this will mean that we'll have more time/resources to build a better, more consistent front-end experience. I'm personally interested in this, because I'm the designer for Jobs (hi! :) and our lack of design/messaging patterns hurts my heart and makes me sad.

The design team is also working on a pattern library. This is a long-term project, and you probably won't see immediate changes to Jobs - but our team is very, very aware that this is a problem and we have many ideas about how to fix it. I hope you'll see those ideas in practice sooner rather than later.

Comment: I understand all of that but the proposed fixes short term might be ten minutes.  While at the same time you can work on the long term fix.  These design changes are pretty simple stuff.

Comment: @JonH Yes, it would appear to be a 10 minute change. It's not. I understand that my response above is not exactly what you asked for, but I'm doing my best to be transparent with you :/